# Javascript return number less than 100 given an array with numbers and strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given below, how do I write a function that will return a number less than 100?

```
const myArray = ['hello', 3, true, 18, 10,, 99 'ten', false]

const isLessThan100 = (array) => {
  // how to do this? Solution enter here
}
```

I think it involves the filter method, but im not sure how to filter both a number less than 100, and is not a string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be you have convert that each item to an integer and then compare?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. is it a single value or more than one values?

Answer (score 4):

you can check if it is a number first like this

```
const myArray = ['hello', 3, true, 18, 10, 99, 'ten', false];

const isLessThan100 = myArray.filter(item => {
  return (typeof item === "number") && item < 100;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

You can first check whether the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) the item is `number` or not, then check if it is less than `100`.

You can reduce the code to a single line by removing the curly braces.

Try [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like the following way:

```js
const myArray = ['hello', 3, true, 18, 10,, 99, 'ten', false]

const isLessThan100 = (array) => array.filter(num => typeof(num) === "number" && num < 100);

console.log(isLessThan100(myArray))
```

```css
const isLessThan100 = (array)
```

Comment: identical solution, and you updated yours 7 mins after I posted mine :-)

Comment: and you edited yours again. this is unbelievable. :-)

Comment: @D.Seah, unbelievable???  what do you think....why the edit button is for?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short-ish one using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const myArray = ['hello', 3, true, 18, 10, 99, 101, 'ten', false];

const isLessThan100 = a => a.filter(e => +e === e && e < 100);

console.log(isLessThan100(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting only a single value, you could reduce the array.

```js
const
    array = ['hello', 3, true, 18, 10,, 99, 'ten', false],
    isLessThan100 = array => array.reduce((r, v) =>
        typeof v === 'number' && v < 100 && (typeof r !== 'number' || v > r)
            ? v
            : r,
        undefined);

console.log(isLessThan100(array));
```